# Laravel mix and jQuery plugin issue, $().plugin not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

I use Laravel mix to manage my js files, here is my app.js :

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./jquery-1.11.2.min.js');

require('./jquery.easing.1.3.js');
require('./bootstrap.min.js');
require('./SmoothScroll.js');
require('./jquery.scrollTo.min.js');
require('./jquery.localScroll.min.js');
require('./jquery.viewport.mini.js');
require('./jquery.countTo.js');
require('./jquery.appear.js');
require('./jquery.sticky.js');
require('./jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js');
require('./jquery.fitvids.js');
require('./owl.carousel.min.js');
require('./isotope.pkgd.min.js');
require('./imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js');
require('./jquery.magnific-popup.min.js');
require('./gmap3.min.js');
require('./wow.min.js');
require('./masonry.pkgd.min.js');
require('./jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js');
require('./all.js');
```

the all.js contains all the logic and inits , so my problem is that **some** jQuery plugins don't work :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function
>       at init_lightbox (index.js?id=f95f3419a2325063a526:11289)

when I load my js in the traditional way `<script ...` in the same order as above all works but when I require 
them it throws the error, please help, thank You

EDIT:

The init functions fire after the ducument is ready (in all.js) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).trigger("resize");            
        init_classic_menu();
        init_fullscreen_menu();
        init_side_panel();
        init_lightbox();
        init_parallax();
        init_shortcodes();
        init_tooltips();
        init_counters();
        init_team();
        initPageSliders();
        init_map();
        init_wow();
        init_masonry();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution was to install the jQuery via npm and instead of

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./jquery-1.11.2.min.js');
```

do

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

that has solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is [a problem](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/288) with Magnific-Popup

> It's because Modernizr adds video CSS class to HTML element, which is
>   the same as selector of your popup.

Do you happen to use class `video` anywhere on your website? Maybe `Magnific-Popup` is accidentally targeting your HTML element.

Comment: hi, thank You , unfortunately this is not the case, the functions are fired after the document ready event , I have updated the question and included the snippet

Comment: Cool, I just edited my answer. It kind of makes sense because we would see something like `$ is not defined` if jQuery was not initialized correctly.

Comment: nope, not a single "video" class, the issue must be form the webpack , coz if I load the scripts on the page in a traditional way using <script> tags it all works

Comment: Maybe turn off js minification?

Comment: it is in dev mode so it is not minifying